# Collect the progress of long running multiprocessing.Pool workers

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a multiprocessing.Pool that runs a number of processes. Each process takes a long time and I want to be able to track the status of each worker. Here is the idea:

```
def f(tag):
   for percent_completion in range(100):
      time.sleep(1)
      print(f'{tag}: {percent_completion}%'


pool = Pool(processes=2)
pool.map(f, list('ABCD'))
```

However, I need to process the workers' progress in a centralized way. For example, I want print out something like this every X seconds:

```
A: 13%, B: 12%, C: 0%, D: 0%
```

My plan was to have a separate process that prints the status, and this process needs to receive the progress report from the worker processes. The problem I bumped into is how to send the progress information from the worker processes to the reporting process. By the way, status processing does not have to be done in a separate process - I am okay with doing this in the main.

I'd love to be able to pass a single queue into which each worker process puts the progress report; something like this (I tried using a simple Queue, but it looks like it is not allowed for Pool, so I am using the Manager's queue):

```
def f(tag, q):
    for pct in range(10):
        q.put((tag, pct))
        time.sleep(0.2)


def print_status(q: Queue):
    status = {}
    while True:
        tag, pct = q.get(block=True, timeout=3)
        status[tag] = pct
        print(status)
        time.sleep(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = Manager()
    p = Process(target=print_status, args=(m.Queue(),))
    p.start()
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    pool.starmap(f, [(x, m.Queue()) for x in 'ABCDEF'])
```

This fails with an error I don't understand:

```
Process Process-2: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in
_bootstrap
    self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/home/alex/code/trading/training/test.py", line 16, in print_status
    tag, pct = q.get(block=True, timeout=3)   File "<string>", line 2, in get   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 850, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result) multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 250, in serve_client
    self.id_to_local_proxy_obj[ident] KeyError: '7fc1cc17f5b0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 252, in serve_client
    raise ke   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 246, in serve_client
    obj, exposed, gettypeid = id_to_obj[ident] KeyError: '7fc1cc17f5b0'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/util.py", line 300, in
_run_finalizers
    finalizer()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/util.py", line 224, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 691, in
_finalize_manager
    process.join(timeout=1.0)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 149, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 44, in wait
    if not wait([self.sentinel], timeout):   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 931, in wait
    ready = selector.select(timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/selectors.py", line 415, in select
    fd_event_list = self._selector.poll(timeout) KeyboardInterrupt
```

I tried other ways like passing the status dict to each process hoping that each worker will be able to fill it in, but it didn't work either. What I'd really want to avoid is to creating a separate queue for each worker and then collect the progress reports from each.

Could you please recommend a nice way how it can be done?

Comment: If you want to use a single queue, why are you creating a new queue every time?

Comment: @user2357112. Thank you for the suggestion. I was under impression that it is not creating a new queue, but rather returning a reference to some internal queue owned by the Manager. Anyway, I tried to create the queue once, and then passing it to the process and the pool, and it kinda works. It prints the status as expected, but it also gives a KeyboardInterrupt exception at the end ("Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs"). Don't understand why yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

I shared the same Manager's queue across all processes. It was also important to add m.shutdown() - without it there was a KeyboardError (why keyboard?!) at the end. Changed the "main" part to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = Manager()
    q = m.Queue()
    p = Process(target=print_status, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    pool.starmap(f, [(x, q) for x in 'ABCDEF'])
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
    m.shutdown()
```

Now it prints the progress status as expected.

Problem solved. Thank you, *@user2357112*.